Finding equations of $\mathbb{C}^*$-curves in $\mathbb{C}^2$
This is a follow-up of this question on mathoverflow. I understand that very rarely $\mathbb{C}^*$-curves in $\mathbb{C}^3$ will be a complete intersection. But, we know that
in $\mathbb{C}^2$, every curve is given by one equation (every divisor is principal). But I am still not able to find the equation defining a $\mathbb{C}^*$-curve in $\mathbb{C}^2$. More precisely,
fix co-prime positive integers $t_1,t_2$.
Suppose we have a $\mathbb{C}^*$ action on $\mathbb{C}^2\setminus\{0\}$ defined by
$$\mathbb{C}^* \times \mathbb{C}^2 \setminus \{0\} \to \mathbb{C}^2 \setminus \{0\}\, \mbox{ sending } (\lambda, (x_1,x_2))\, \mbox{ to }\, (\lambda^{t_1}x_1,\lambda^{t_2}x_2).$$ Fix a point $(x_1,x_2) \in \mathbb{C}^2 \setminus \{0\}$. Denote by $C$ the closure of the orbit of the $\mathbb{C}^*$-action on the point $(x_1,x_2)$. What is the equation defining $C$?

For $(1,1)$ it is $z_{2}^{t_{1}} = z_{1}^{t_{2}} $, for a general point you should be able to work out the constant.

@NickL But this equation has more solutions than those on the $\mathbb{C}^$ curve. For example, $(\mu_{t_2}\lambda^{t_1},\mu_{t_1}\lambda^{t_2})$ also satisfy the equation, but not on the $\mathbb{C}^$-curve, where $\mu_j$ is a $j$-th root of unity.

This is a response to your comment which is too long for an answer and will look nicer with spaced out equations, also it gives the gist of the proof of the claimed equation. Let $\mu_{t_2} = e^{\frac{2\pi i k_2}{t_2}}$, $\mu_{t_1} = e^{\frac{2\pi i k_1}{t_1}}$ be a general pair of roots of unity.
Then, by the chinese remainder theorem there exists an integer $k$ with  $$k = k_{1} \mod t_{1}$$ $$k = k_{2} \mod t_{2}.$$
Then let $$\alpha =  e^{\frac{2\pi i k}{t_1 t_2}} $$.
Then $((\alpha \lambda)^{t_{1}},(\alpha \lambda)^{t_{2}})  = (\mu_{t_{2}} \lambda^{t_{1}}, \mu_{t_{1}} \lambda^{t_{2}})$.

Cool! Did not think of CRT. Thanks!
